# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 has broken web templates

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013, updates

After installing Update 4 on my Desktop workstation and laptop computers, both of them have lost the web templates.

When I try to create a new C# web project I only can see this:
[image]

And If I select it, then I can see this error:
[image]

I write the error message here to future search:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this 
>   problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation 
>   on Customizing Project Templates.

Any idea how can I recover this templates?

Comment: I have this same issue.

Comment: Same here. Visual Studio 2014 Ultimate, with update 3. When I installed the update 4, got that error also.

Comment: I had this issue. Did a repair and it's now fixed. (Control Panel/Uninstall a program/View installed updates/Repair)

Comment: Doing what @ThomasVeil has commented have solved the problem in both machines. Please, put it as Answer to accept as resolution.  Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this issue! Did a 'Repair' and it's now fixed!

To repair, go to Control Panel/Uninstall a program/View installed updates/Uninstall/Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Check if All the templates are present in the given directories
"Visual Studio installation path"\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\
"Visual Studio installation path"\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\

then Open command with administrator navigate to "Visual Studio installation path"\Common7\IDE\" and Type devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates

If this doesn't Help Reinstalling definitely will

Comment: Cleaning Templates cache and reinstalling with `/installVSTemplates` doesn't solve the situation.  As I said in my question this behaviour was happened installing update 4 on my both dev workstations so I prefer to wait a solution before reinstalling Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4.

Comment: Same for me, again.  :-(

Comment: I just ended up uninstalling VS, and then using the full installer from MSDN including Update 4.